# VBA: Sumproductc return empty value (Matrix Multiplication)

Tags: vba, matrix-multiplication, portfolio

I'm trying to do some matrix multiplication in VBA, but I keep getting an error. I've tried to define all the vectors and matrices and do the calculations one stop at a time and it looks like the =MMult function is working correctly, but when using =SumProduct the value returned is 0.

This is my code for this sub (I've left out some formatting):

```
Sub StockAnalysis()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Stocks As Integer
Dim TableStart As Integer
Dim TableEnd As Integer
Dim CorrTableStart
Dim CovTableStart As Integer
Dim InvCovTableStart As Integer

Dim AuxiliaryA As Integer
Dim AuxiliaryB As Integer
Dim AuxiliaryC As Integer
Dim AuxiliaryD As Integer

'Count the amount of stocks
Stocks = 0
For i = 1 To 20
    If Worksheets("MainSheet").Cells(i + 2, 2) <> 0 Then
        Stocks = Stocks + 1
    Else
        Stocks = Stocks
    End If
Next

'Deleting previous TempSheet
For Each Worksheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name = "TempSheet" Then
        Worksheet.Delete
    End If
Next

'Defining start and end points of the tables
TableStart = Stocks + 3
TableEnd = TableStart + Stocks
CorrTableStart = 9
CovTableStart = CorrTableStart + Stocks + 2
InvCovTableStart = 13 + (Stocks * 2)
RiskFreeRateStart = InvCovTableStart + 2 + Stocks

'Transposing Means are creating One Vector 
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"
Worksheets("TempSheet").Visible = xlSheetHidden
Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(1, 1) = "Stocks"
Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(1, 2) = "Mean"
Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(1, 3) = "Vector"
For j = 1 To Stocks
    Symbol = Worksheets("All stocks").Cells(1, 1 + j)
    Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(j + 1, 1) = Symbol

    Mean = Worksheets("All stocks").Cells(2, TableStart + j)
    Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(j + 1, 2) = Mean

    Worksheets("TempSheet").Cells(j + 1, 3) = 1
Next

'--------------------Calculations--------------------

MeanVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(1 + Stocks, 2))
OneVector = Worksheets("TempSheet").Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(1 + Stocks, 3))

ReDim MatrixInvCov(1 To Stocks, 1 To Stocks)
For i = 1 To Stocks
    For j = 1 To Stocks
        MatrixInvCov(i, j) = Worksheets("All stocks") _
            .Cells(InvCovTableStart + i, TableStart + j).Value
    Next
Next

AuxiliaryMeanMM = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(MatrixInvCov, MeanVector)

AuxiliaryOneMM = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(MatrixInvCov, OneVector)

AuxiliaryA = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(MeanVector, AuxiliaryMeanMM)
AuxiliaryB = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(MeanVector, AuxiliaryMeanMM)
AuxiliaryC = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(MeanVector, AuxiliaryOneMM)
AuxiliaryD = AuxiliaryA - AuxiliaryC - AuxiliaryB ^ 2



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

In Excel "A" would be written like this:

=Sumproduct(MeanVector;MMULT(MatrixInvCov;MeanVector))

The dimensions of the matrix and vectors are correct, since AuxiliaryOneMM, AuxiliaryMeanMM, MeanVector and OneVectore are [3x1] while MatrixInvCov is a [3x3] Matrix

Here is a picture of the locals window, it looks like it the vectors and matrix are correct, but A, B, C and D are all 0.

[image]

Pictures of TempSheet and All Stocks if needed:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Dim AuxiliaryA As Integer
> Dim AuxiliaryB As Integer
> Dim AuxiliaryC As Integer
> Dim AuxiliaryD As Integer
> ```

You're dimming your results `As Integer`, they will be 0 for whatever result less than 1. Looking at the values in the watch window, they seem to be small values, so this is the most likely reason.

```
Dim AuxiliaryA As Double, AuxiliaryB As Double, AuxiliaryC As Double, AuxiliaryD As Double
```

For scientific calculations, I think you should dim all your variables `As Double` unless you have some reasonable justification.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this did solve the problem!

I didn't even look at the dimming of the variables. I guess I need to read up a bit on this part.

Answer (score 0):

You can also evaluate Excel Formulas (not tested):

```
MatrixInvCovAddr = Cells(InvCovTableStart + 1, TableStart + 1).Resize(stocks,stocks).Address

AuxiliaryMeanMM = Sheet("TempSheet").Evaluate("Sumproduct(B2:B" & 1 + Stocks & _ 
           ",MMULT('All stocks'!" & MatrixInvCovAddr & ", B2:B" & 1 + Stocks & "))")
```